# Is there a word to describe a person who thinks he knows the fact, only after a fact has been revealed, but not before?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I have a friend that would consistently say, "I could have told you that," only after the fact is said.

But when I test him before the fact is revealed, he wouldn't know the answer. He has narcissistic traits.

Answer (score 1):

Mr.Know it all.. (its a sarcastic way to refer a person who acts as though he/she knows everything)
check [this](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Mr.%20know%20it%20all) for reference.

Reference:
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Mr.%20know%20it%20all

Comment: This has the makings of a good answer. Can you please add a reference and synopsis to it is of greater value to future viewers?

Comment: @Bookeater - updated with reference :)

Comment: Well-done! I've added it as plain text as well, that is site policy to compensate for link rot. You already had my upvote :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that is a [***windbag***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/windbag). (And a [***copycat***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/copycat) as well.)

windbag

> A person who talks at length but says little of any value:
>   *'I think he’s a pompous old windbag'*

copycat

> (Especially in children’s use) a person who copies another’s behaviour, dress, or ideas:
>   *'all writers are copycats'*

References:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/windbag
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/copycat

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a [Monday-morning quarterback](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/monday-morning-quarterback) to me:

> a person who criticizes the actions or decisions of others after the fact, using hindsight to assess situations and specify alternative solutions. *[dictionary.com]*

Answer (score 0):

You could call a person like that *[Captain Hindsight](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Captain%20Hindsight)*:-

> A stupid ass superhero from the South Park episode Coon 2: Hindsight.
>   He flies around the world providing hindsight after every catastrophy
>   that happens, but doesn't actually do anything helpful. [Urban Dictionary]

although it would be understood only by South Park fans, I guess.

www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Captain+Hindsight

Comment: I like this reference, just wish there's a single word to describe this.